# Pandas Dataframe Column Value Conversion from string to binary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert string values in a column to binary values.For example in the below table - the mapping will be like this {'cinema':0, 'education':1}.

[image]

I have defined a small function as below -

```
def numconv(a):
return a.map({'education' : 1,'cinema' : 0})
```

and then I have used 'apply' function to update the values in the dataframe -

```
train_docs['Class'] = train_docs['Class'].apply(numconv)
```

But I am getting error as below -

[image]

What I am doing wrng here?It should work as per my understanding.

Comment: I think `map` is solution here.

Comment: This would likely be faster to do in a vectorized fashion if its a large dataframe e.g. `df['Class]=np.where((df['Class']=='education'),1,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.apply` method of `pandas.Series` given function should accept what that `pandas.Series` is holding, in this case `str`s,

```
def numconv(a):
    return a.map({'education' : 1,'cinema' : 0})
```

will not work if `a` is `str`, you might repair it by changing to

```
def numconv(a):
    return {'education' : 1,'cinema' : 0}[a]
```

or in this case just use `.replace` method of `pandas.Series` like so

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Class":["education","education","education","cinema","cinema"]})
df["Class"].replace({'education' : 1,'cinema' : 0},inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output

```
   Class
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      0
```

Beware that function I proposed will fail if any other value will appears, whilst `.replace` ignores unknown values

Answer (score 1):

you can use map -

```
a = {'education' : 1,'cinema' : 0}
train_docs['Class'] = train_docs['Class'].map(a)
```